# Difference of the long integer python object between jupyter and pycharm?

Tags: python

I wrote 2 codeblocks as follow, and run them in different ways with same anaconda virtual environment:

The first is:

```
a = 1431324 # just a long integer
b = 1431324 # same as a
print(a is b) # the result is 'False' running in Jupyter; the result is 'True' running in Pycharm
```

In Pycharm, it just like `a = 1431324` and `b = a`, but actually, it should be different.

The second is:

```
a,b = 1431324,1431324
print(a is b) # the result is 'True' running in both Jupyter and Pycharm
```

I know that for short integers, python build the objects in advance which would never be garbage-collected, but for long integers, python would not creat object in advance.

But it seems that sometimes python never creat two object for same long integer. So, I am confused that:

1. What is the difference between the 2 value assignment ways above in object level?
2. Why the result is difference between Pycharm and Jupyter when run the same code?

Comment: If two equal integers are created *in the same compilation*, they will use the same object (whether or not they are in the range that is normally cached).  So the difference you're seeing is simply due to line-by-line execution vs. running a whole script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this function:

```py
def f():
    a = 1431324
    b = 1431324
    return a is b
```

It would probably return `True`.

When you write `a,b = 1431324,1431324` in to your REPL, it basically does "build the tuple with two elements, `1431324` and `1431324`, and unpack it and store it in the two variables, `a` and `b`". The two constants `1431324` can be merged to be the same (and the peephole optimizer will replace building the tuple with a pre-built constant `(1431324, 1431324)`.

You can find this constant by looking at the bytecode:

```py
>>> import dis
>>> code = compile('a,b = 1431324,1431324', '<str>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(code)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1431324, 1431324))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> code.co_consts
((1431324, 1431324), None)
>>> code.co_consts[0][0] is code.co_consts[0][1]
True
```

When you have two different lines, they are compiled separately, so the constants aren't merged:

```py
>>> a = compile('a = 1431324', '<str>', 'exec')
>>> a.co_consts
(1431324, None)
>>> b = compile('b = 1431324', '<str>', 'exec')
>>> b.co_consts
(1431324, None)
>>> a.co_consts[0] is b.co_consts[0]
False
```

This also happens in the PyCharm REPL. Perhaps you were entering multiple lines at a time, or were running a full script (which is compiled to bytecode before being executed beforehand, so the constants are merged)